# Solubility of Forskolin in ethanol

Tags: neuroscience, cell-biology, cell-culture, stem-cells, organic-chemistry

I am interested in using forskolin in cell culture medium. Does anyone know how to make solution of 10 microM forskolin in 5% ethanol or less. I would like to avoid using DMSO as a solvent.
Thank you. L.

Answer (score 1):

Sigma gives a solubility of 200 microMole in water containing 2% ethanol.
They state:

> Forskolin is soluble in water (with 2% ethanol) up to 0.2 mM by first
>   dissolving in ethanol at 5 mg/mL and doing subsequent dilutions with
>   water.

The datasheet can be found [here](http://www.sigmaaldrich.com/content/dam/sigma-aldrich/docs/Sigma/Product_Information_Sheet/f6886pis.pdf).

Comment: Thank you for you answer. We will probably try that,even though we tried to avoid the part where we would first dissolve it in absolute ethanol, as it gives some concerns toward inhibition of its ability to raise cAMP levels. Dont know if that is a genuine concern.

Comment: I don't remember the last time we prepared forskolin, but I don't remember this was a problem.